# How can I get a DataFrame to preserve index ordering when using to_dict and from_dict?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.Dataframe` that looks like this,

```
        Column_1
index_x value_x
index_y value_x
1ndex_1 value_1
2ndex_2 value_2
3ndex_3 value_3
```

Initially, I turn turn this into a dictionary, trying to preserve order by utilizing an OrderedDict,

```
r = df.to_dict(into=OrderedDict)
```

The return value of this is

```
OrderedDict([('Column_1', OrderedDict([('index_x', 'value_x'), 
                                       ('index_y', 'value_y'), 
                                       ('1ndex_1', 'value_1'), 
                                       ('2ndex_2', 'value_2'), 
                                       ('3ndex_3', 'value_3')]))])
```

This is the correct order and looks exactly like my table. However, when then immediately trying to reconstruct it using,

```
DataFrame.from_dict(r)
```

the result is,

```
         Column_1
1ndex_1  value_1
2ndex_2  value_2
3ndex_3  value_3
index_x  value_x
index_y  value_y
```

It seems that that DataFrame is being resorted in the index and it sorting it by the alphabetical values. How can this be prevented? I want my `to_dict` and `from_dict` to return identical dataframes with the index ordering intacted.

Comment: This is a known issue and has a ton of Issues on GitHub the primary issue branch being [ENH: Preserve key order when passing list of dicts to DataFrame on py 3.6+#27309](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/27309) But either of the workarounds in the linked thread should work.

Comment: I wish I had a better answer for you. If you don't specifically need the dictionary structure there are many ways to save and load a dataframe that would work.

Comment: The first answer in your link provided my desired behavior. Not sure how to accept answers from a comment though.

Comment: That's all right. I'm just glad you have something that works.